# Pass a NSDictionary as parameter to UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to pass a `NSArray` as a parameter to `UITapGestureRecognizer` and access it in downloadOptionPressed method. How can I do this ?

The `NSArray`

```
NSArray *parameters = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentTrack, nil];
```

Creating the `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *downloadOptionPressed = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(timeFrameLabelTapped:)];
    [downloadOption addGestureRecognizer:downloadOptionPressed];
```

The `downloadOptionPressed` method

```
-(void)downloadOptionPressed:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

}
```

Comment: Can't you make a property and access it?

Comment: And conform `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`?

Comment: The selector is handed the gesture as you noticed.  Why not just make an array that is accessible to the method?

Comment: One option is to make it a property. But I will probably need to pass more parameters as well.

Comment: Make an options object which has your array and any other option and set to a property and access it from method.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal did you check my answer? you can do this using Associated Objects easily.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't store the information in the owning view controller?  Is it for abstraction?

You can always extend UITapGestureRecognizer to carry more data:

```
@interface UserDataTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer
@property (nonatomic, strong) id userData;
@end

@implementation UserDataTapGestureRecognizer
@end
```

...

```
UserDataTapGestureRecognizer *downloadOptionPressed =
    [[UserDataTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
    action:@selector(timeFrameLabelTapped:)];
downloadOptionPressed.userData = parameters;
```

...

```
- (void)downloadOptionPressed:(UserDataTapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSArray *parameters = recognizer.userData;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **associated object** to pass argument along with tap gesture instance.

You can check this [objective-c-associated-objects](http://labs.vectorform.com/2011/07/objective-c-associated-objects/)

It will solve your problem.

Comment: What an absolutely awesome, rarely discussed feature! Much cleaner than subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with passing an index is enough, in that case the tag property view is your ally. In the following exampled I pretended to add a long press into a tableview cell. And once the event was triggered, I just wanted to know which cell was long pressed:

```
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPress:")
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

...

```
func longPress(guesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("\(guesture.view!.tag)")} }
```